# How to use MongoDB ReferenceField in Backbone.js?

Tags: python, mongodb, backbone.js, flask, mongoengine

I have two Mongo documents defined in Flask:

```
class Category(db.Document):
    name = db.StringField(max_length=255, required=True)
    created = db.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now, required=False)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Event(db.Document):
    description = db.StringField(max_length=255, required=True)
    created = db.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now, required=False)
    categories = db.ListField(db.ReferenceField(Category),required=False)
    meta = {
        'indexes': ['-description','created'],
        'ordering': ['-created']
    }
```

and I use a tiny REST api to serve my Backbone models.

```
window.EventModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {},
    initialize: function Event(){},
    validate: function(a){},
    url: function(){
        return this.id ? '/events/' + this.id : '/events';
    }

})

window.CategoryModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {},
    initialize: function Expense(){},
    validate: function(a){},
    url: function(){
        [...]
    }

})
```

Here is my JSON response:

```
[{
        "description": "MyEvent",
        "created": {"$date": 1338404831615},
        "id": "4fc653ffbe51030887000004",
        "categories": [{
                "$ref": "category", 
                "$id": {"$oid": "4fc652efbe51030887000001"}
        }, {
                "$ref": "category",
                "$id": {"$oid": "4fc65304be51030887000002"}
        }]
}]
```

I'd like to know how to link the Event model to the Category Model into Backbone?

NB: Backbone-relationnal does not work as expected in this case.

Any ideas? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Interestingly, Mongo doesn't seem to want to allow the `$oid` attribute: `BSON::InvalidKeyName - $oid - key must not start with '$'`.